# Reinstalling Apache on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, apt, apache-httpd, raspbian

I installed Apache 2 on my Raspberry Pi but was not able to configure it properly.

I then tried to remove it and install again. To remove it I used the command `sudo apt-get purge apache2` and then deleted the directory `/etc/apache2` with the command `rm -r apache2`.

The problem is that now when I'm trying to reinstall Apache it is not creating the directory in `/etc`. How can I reinstall Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Type 
`sudo apt-get purge apache2*`

This will get rid of all packages starting with apache2, then

Type `sudo apt-get autoremove`

It'll uninstall the packages that were installed by other packages and no longer needed. Then install apache. Hope this works.

Comment: If reinstall works then I think `aptitude reinstall apache2*` (as root) should do a cleaner job.

Comment: @McSinyx no. You want to let the `apt*` tools work out the dependencies and install them as necessary. Just `aptitude install apache2` is sufficient.